# Mainclass not found or loaded in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

i have imported an JavaProject via Git. In the next step I want to test a simple Hello-World-Programm.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

If i perform a right-click on Test.java in the Package-Explorer and do "Run - as Java-Application" it says:

Fehler: Hauptklasse Test konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden [ Error: Main-Class Test can not be found or loaded.

Is there anything like Ant which can interfere with a simple run-command?

In another project, everything works just fine, with my Java-JDK.

Comment: Have you checked in the markers view or in the problems view that you have no error?

Comment: There are no entrys in "problems" or "markers" related to this project. After clicking "Run" there is no bin-folder in the project-folder

Comment: Check the "package" declaration at the top of the java file. If it doesn't match the relative directory path of the java file, eclipse won't find the compiled class file at run-time.

Comment: It is placed in the default-package for testing, but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Did the compilation using 'javac' result in class file?. Did you check that?. Also make sure that you are having that class file in the directory from which you are issuing the 'java' command.

Comment: It works fine with javac Test.java and java Test from the command line. But Eclipse is doing something strange in this project, what influence are there, that a simple run-command doesn't result in something similar to this command-chain from the command-line ?

Answer (score 0):

this problem really killed me as well and by chance I just discovered what was the problem with my project:

Eclipse throws this error message when the **project name** has illegal characters like ":". 
Deleting those has solved the problem for me.